# One of my soap call function in c is returning status as 12

Tags: c, soap, gsoap

In one of my gSOAP code in c, my soapCall function is returning 12.

Can you please tell me what is the error code or value 12 in retun, means in soap.

Comment: [The w3c technical report on SOAP](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383510) suggests error messages are strings instead of numbers. Perhaps you should give some specific code that reproduces your problem so there's something more concrete to discuss?

Comment: a code snippet should be added in order to send an accurate answer

Answer (score 1):

This value is defined in stdsoap2.h:

```
#define SOAP_FAULT                      12
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not mean something special regarding the SOAP protocol.

It is a gsoap error. This means that your code has problem. If you are implementing a client code, please check that your request arrives at the "soap server". If not then the problem is on the client code.

```
int soap_call_c__add(struct soap *soap, char *URL, char *action, double a, double b, double& result
```

In the above call please notice that the arguments have some specific reason, ie the first is the soap environment, the second the destination URL etc.

Answer (score 0):

On poor standard implementors, usually they use the code 12 (SOAP_FAULT) to indicate 
a generic error on a standard valid input they are not able to manage.

For example, in my case, interrogating an Onvif-S compatible camera, an optional value I did not provide resulted in this error; I solved by filling the optional value.